# How do I lock the terminal screen from the terminal?

Tags: linux, debian, terminal

Related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/7776/how-do-i-lock-the-desktop-screen-via-command-line but not the same answer.

How do I lock the terminal screen from the terminal in Linux? On HP-UX it was

```
$ lock
Key:
Again:
Locked
```

but I currently get

```
$ lock
bash: lock: command not found
```

In this case this is a true vterm; there's no X behind it to lock.

I have tagged this debian, but the broader scope the answer the better.

Comment: What's wrong with `vlock`, and why didn't `man -k lock` find it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: `man -k lock` didn't find it because vlock wasn't installed and Google wasn't much help either. Write up answer as it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As provided by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams in comments:

The command to lock a terminal is `vlock`. When executed with no arguments, it locks the current terminal.

```
$ vlock
This TTY is now locked.

Please press [ENTER] to unlock.
[username]'s password:
$
```

`vlock` is not installed in debian by default if the system was installed via `debootstrap`; `apt-get install vlock` will install it.